# Completing the square of $|z|^2-z\frac{k^2\bar{z}_1-l^2\bar{z}_2}{k^2-l^2}-\bar{z}\frac{k^2z_1-l^2z_2}{k^2-l^2}=\frac{k^2|z_1|^2+l^2|z_2|^2}{k^2-l^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$|z|^2-z\frac{k^2\bar{z}_1-l^2\bar{z}_2}{k^2-l^2}-\bar{z}\frac{k^2z_1-l^2z_2}{k^2-l^2}=-\frac{k^2|z_1|^2-l^2|z_2|^2}{k^2-l^2}$$

Is it possible to complete the square of the above? I see a "Quadratic in $z$", but I realise that $\bar{z}$ is by no means a constant. Then in a the constant in this case $0$? Ie I have a quadratic as $ax^2 + bx + 0$

It gives this result [Complex Numbers - Locus of $k|z-z_1|=l|z-z_2|$ where $k\neq l$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320996/complex-numbers-locus-of-kz-z-1-lz-z-2-where-k-neq-l?noredirect=1) but I tried doing the algebra myself and did'nt get anywhere. In particular, how does the **conjugate** disspear and the **absolute value** appear?

Comment: "*how does the conjugate disspear and the absolute value appear*" $-$ Using $|z|^2 = z \bar z\,$.

Comment: Ok. Well that requires combining $z$ and $\bar{z}$ which I cant see a nice way to do due to the $z_1$ and $z_2$

Comment: *Hint:* $|z-a|^2 = (z-a) (\bar z - \bar a) = |z|^2 - z \bar a - \bar z a + |a|^2$

Comment: @Martin R Then there is no way to complete the square and my interpretation of a "quadratic" is incorrect?

Comment: I don't know what your interpretation is. The left-hand side is of the form $|z|^2 - z \bar a - \bar z a$ and that can be “completed” to $|z|^2 - z \bar a - \bar z a + |a|^2 = |z-a|^2$, which leads to the desired equation for a circle.

Comment: Oh ok. My interpretation was a quadratic equation where $z$ replaces $x$ in $ax^2 + bx + c$. Do you see?

Comment: I see what you mean, but the given equation is not of that form. I don’t know if what I explained above is called "completing the square" or not, I probably wouldn’t call it like that.

Comment: I suggest not using the phrase "complete the square" in reference to an equation. Isolate some expression of interest, write it in a different way  involving squares. For example, begin with $f=axy + bx + cy$  and try $aF = a^2xy + abx + acy.$  We think this is related to $(ax +c)(ay+b).$ Not perfect, $(ax +c)(ay+b)= a^2xy+abx+acy+bc$  so that $(ax +c)(ay+b) -bc = a^2xy+abx+acy = aF. \; \;$   If the original $F$ were set equal to something else, we have alternatives

Comment: For user71207,  I have a detailed solution for this problem if you still require it.  I'm currently writing it in Latex.